# Raspberry pi is in a reboot-loop

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3

I wrote this python program for my Raspberry Pi 3:

```
import time, os

time.sleep(20)
os.system("reboot")
```

I made an edit in the `/etc/rc.local` that the program will autostart.

The edit is only adding the following line before `exit 0`:
`python /home/pi/reboot.py`

But now my Raspberry pi 3 is in a reboot loop.
How can I delete the line I added in `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: Please read this first : [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the SD card, mount the filesystem on the sd card on your linux machine and edit the files or the program in question.

Comment: Rewrite the SD card?